# I'm writing a fuse filesystem. How do I pass extra data to fuse_operations?

Tags: c, global-variables, fuse

I'm writing a fuse filesystem.

How do I pass extra data to the functions in `struct fuse_operations`?

In particular, how can I access the `void *`, that I can set in `fuse_main()` and similar, from functions in `struct fuse_operations`?

I'm looking for a method other than global variables, as I am making my fuse operations testable.

Answer (score 0):

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/structfuse__context.html

I can get the data with `fuse_get_context`.  I should be able to fake this function in my tests.

Comment: If you have the answer you should mark it answered. Is this enough for you?